# Java JNI - Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java, c, dll, java-native-interface

I tried create a JNI helloworld project using [this tutorial.](http://adamish.com/blog/archives/620)
I completed every step on the page. Unfortunately after trying to call the programm with `java -Djava.library.path="C:/Users/Philipp/Desktop/jni" HelloWorld` i get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Philipp\Desktop\jni\helloworld.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:3)
```

There are a few questions on stackoverflow with this type of error, unfortunately none of the solutions are working for me.

I want to stay on JDK 64 bit, so I guess I have to compile my C-code for a 64-bit machine. I tried using the `-m64` keyword: `gcc -shared HelloWorld.c -I"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/include" -I"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/include/win32" -o libhelloworld.dll -m64` which leads to the following error:

```
HelloWorld.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
 #include <jni.h>
 ^
```

What do I have to do to get it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `x86_64` `GCC` toolchain to compile it for x64(if you are in windows, probably mingw). And you are right, as your JDK is AMD64, so the SO/DLL need to be AMD64 too.

In windows you either install `x86_64-w64-mingw32-` toolchain by cygwin env or msys2, or go for Microsoft C compiler.

Comment: I've only programmed with Java so far, so I'm quite new to the whole C-world. I've downloaded the toolchain with cygwin and have a folder on C:\cygwin64 with a lot of exe-files in C:\cygwin64\bin. What do I have to do to compile my .c file using cygwin64?

Comment: Run the cygwin setup again. once it shows the available packages, select the x86_64-w64-mingw32 toolchain and packages. Another solution is the msys2 which comes with easier stuff and pacman which is piece of cake. NOte cygwin itself is not a compiler! but it comes with `GCC` toolchains. C-world is awesome dear, just need some time to get along with stuff and you are perfect.